# What is the difference between "musste", "muss" and "müsste"?

Tags: word-choice

What are the differences between the following sentences:

> Wir wussten nicht, dass die vorhandene Rechtestruktur auch abgebildet werden **musste**.
>
> Wir wussten nicht, dass die vorhandene Rechtestruktur auch abgebildet werden **muss**.
>
> Wir wussten nicht, dass die vorhandene Rechtestruktur auch abgebildet werden **müsste**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- *musste*: Past tense. You were required to do it. This can imply that the deadline is already over.
- *muss*: Present tense. You are required to do it. This can imply that you still have to do it, and that the project is probably not finished.
- *müsste*: Conjunctive. This might make sense when you're not already into the project, but rather just gave the customer an estimate which does not contain this thing. It can also mean that you still think it should *not* be done.

The difference between the first two is subtle, and I'm not sure if it will always get the point across. If what you mean is clear from the context, it won't make a huge difference.

Comment: 'müsste' (subjunctive) in conjunction with 'wusste' (indicative mode) sounds just wrong to me.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm, to me, it sounds as though only the second one is correct:

The speaker is apparently talking about a task that includes the "Abbildung" of "vorhandene Rechtestruktur". He and his team were not aware of this and didn't include the latter. The fact that he uses "muss" here implies that the task *always* includes the "AofvR" :)

Another possible sentence would have been:

> Wir wussten nicht, dass die vorhandene Rechtestruktur auch **hätte**
>   abgebildet werden **müssen**.

This restricts his statement to the particular instance where his team failed to include that thing - i.e. it was required in this particular instance (it *may* still be a standard requirement, but not necessarily)

Imo this is the correct version of your example no 1 (which I can picture in a casual conversation)

No 3 doesn't really make sense, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think both 1 and 2 are correct. 1 means it had to be included at least this particular time in the past. 2 means it had to be included but emphasises that it has to be included always anyway. That is why you can use the present tense as well.

- We didn't know it needed to be included
- We didn't know it needs to be included

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. I reformatted your line breaks with bullet points. I still cannot clearly understand what you intend to say this way. Maybe first translating, then explaining? I don't know yet how to read your answer.